# How do I correct this radar plot?

Tags: r, radar-chart

So I am using this code to create a radar plot with my data:

https://medium.com/@rhdzmota/alcohol-and-radar-plots-in-r-with-ggplot2-9ba7ad8c92c

However my plot turns out to be incorrect:
[image]

Because it does not really connect the variables that are located next to each other, not really creating a star. How can I correct this?

Comment: This seems to be a problem with how your data are ordered. You need to make sure that within each faceting group your data points are arranged in the order the labels appear on the radial axis. Without having your data, it's impossible to give you specific code to achieve this.

Comment: Please paste the code you used into the question, questions should be self-contained.